# getting TLE in Spoj-Hotels

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am getting time limit exceeded in [hotels from spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/HOTELS/) .

Here 's my code:

```
int main()
{
    long long n,m;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    scanf("%lld",&m);
    long long a[300005],dp[300005];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) scanf("%lld",&a[i])

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) a[i]+=a[i-1];

    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(a[i]<m){ 
            dp[0] = a[i];
            break; 
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        long long x = a[i-1];
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            a[j]-=x;
        }
        for(int j=n-1;j>=i;j--)
        {
            if(a[j]<=m){ 
            dp[i] = a[j];
            break; 
            }
        }
    }
    long long max_=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        max_ = max(max_,dp[i]);
    }
    printf("%lld\n",max_);
    return 0;
}
```

Explaination:

First of all, i calculated all the values in the array "a" by summing with previous values.Then, calulated the maximum value less than equal to "m" in dp array.Then, i started subtracting from the previous minus the current value from each element of array and stored value in dp array.So,max of dp array would give me the answer.

for e.g. :
 n=5,m=12;

2 1 3 4 5

My array 'a':
2 3 6 10 15

then after 2nd pass :
2 1 4 8 13

then after 3rd pass :
2 1 3 7 12

Here's the code in action: 
[Ideone](http://ideone.com/Wllizb)

Comment: I want to solve it using dp. :)

Comment: did you note in your first for when you are scaning there is no semicolon ";" that is Compilation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has complexity O(n).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[300013];
int main(){
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    long long sumNow = 0;
    long long maxAns = 0;
    int left=0,right=-1;
    while(right!= n-1){
        right++;
        sumNow+=a[right];
        while(sumNow>m){
            sumNow-=a[left];
            left++;
        }
        maxAns = max(maxAns,sumNow);
    }
    printf("%lld", maxAns);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think the condition in the `while` loop will be `right <= n-1` ?

Comment: No))) If `right` will be `n-1` then we will use `a[n]` )))

Comment: But array indexing starts from zero, so there is nothing like `a[n]`!!

Comment: Right, if `right` will be `n-1` then after `right++` `right` will be `n`. And then we use `a[n]` in `sumNow+=a[right]`.

Comment: Oh ok! You were pre-incrementing before using! Missed that part.